# Label missing properties after creation via method

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

Have been searching alot for this, but I think I'm doing something stupidly wrong. I have a lot of labels on my second screen, and they all have the same properties. That's why I create them via a method.
In ViewDidLoad I do this:

```
[self screenTwoLabelMaker:firstNameLabel withFrame:CGRectMake(30, 200, 200, 40) withText:@"First Name"];
```

That method is this one:

```
- (UILabel *)screenTwoLabelMaker:(UILabel *)sender withFrame:(CGRect)frame withText:(NSString *)text
{
    sender = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    sender.text = text;
    sender.frame = frame;
    sender.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:labelFontSize];
    sender.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:sender];
    return sender;
}
```

Then I do this:

```
NSLog(@"firstNameLabel x: %f y:%f w:%f h:%f", firstNameLabel.frame.origin.x, firstNameLabel.frame.origin.y, firstNameLabel.frame.size.width, firstNameLabel.frame.size.height);
```

**But** the result is this:

```
MyApp[9608:60b] firstNameLabel x: 0.000000 y:0.000000 w:0.000000 h:0.000000
```

The weird thing is that the label is being put on the screen on the right place with the right text. So everything should be sunny and warm, no? Well, I also call a similar method for buttons, where there is a tag included. That tag is never active on the button (nil), so further programming for that button is killing me. For now I create them all by hand. Do you guys know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns your new label, so you need to assign it to the variable that you want to hold the reference.  You don't need to pass in the variable to the method as the first thing you do is overwrite it.  Use the following code -

```
firstNameLabel = [self screenTwoMakeLabelwithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 200, 200, 40) text:@"First Name"];


- (UILabel *)screenTwoMakeLabelwithFrame:(CGRect)frame text:(NSString *)text
{
    UILabel newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    newLabel.text = text;
    newLabel.frame = frame;
    newLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:labelFontSize];
    newLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:newLabel];
    return newLabel;
}
```